# A Menu With Table in Qt

Tags: python, qt, pyside2, qmenu

I have Create Menu in QTabelWidget using QMenu And for data entey in table I have used QlineEdit. While I Type in QLineEdit Qmenu lose focus and hide. So How can I Get make such menu which stays while I type in QEditLine.

[image: Image Of My Program]

```
  self.linedit_in_table = QLineEdit(self.parent.Order_tabel)
  self.linedit_in_table.contextMenuEvent
  productWiget = QWidget()
  productMenuWiget = Ui_ProductMenu()
  productMenuWiget.setupUi(productWiget)
  
  product_menu = QMenu(self.grand_parent)
  widegetMenu = QWidgetAction(product_menu)
  widegetMenu.setDefaultWidget(productWiget)
  product_menu.addAction(widegetMenu)

  #self.linedit_in_table.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)


  
  self.parent.Order_tabel.setCellWidget(row, 1, self.linedit_in_table)      
  self.linedit_in_table.setFocus(Qt.OtherFocusReason)
  product_menu.popup(self.parent.Order_tabel.mapToGlobal(QPoint(self.parent.Order_tabel.columnViewportPosition(1)+2,self.parent.Order_tabel.rowViewportPosition(row) +55)))  

  product_menu.setVisible(True)      
  self.linedit_in_table.textEdited.connect(lambda : [product_menu.setVisible(True), self.linedit_in_table.setFocus(Qt.OtherFocusReason)])
```

Comment: A menu is supposed to *always* have focus and be a top level widget. Besides, it seems that what you're doing does *not* need a menu at all, as it can be achieved with a normal widget with appropriate window flags (like `Popup` or `Tool`). Also, beside exceptional cases, if you need a line edit, just use the default editor of the view (see [`openPersistentEditor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#openPersistentEditor).

Answer (score 0):

For tables and trees, the best way is to subclass a **QItemDelegate** and setting a **QLineEdit** with a Completer inside.